# How to set a domain name with php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am new to PHP and Laravel. While virtualhosting with Wamp, I could specify the documentroot, servername and the port number - hence specifying the domain name. But with the command php artisan serve, I am able to specify the port address but not the domain name. 
Is it possible to set the domain name?

also, what is the difference between hosting with this command and with wamp ?

n.b I am new to server side languages, sorry for asking these basics !

EDIT: I've used php artisan serve --host=blog.local --port=8001 but error is showing up[image]

I've cleared the configuration and application cache.

Comment: The `serve` command uses PHP's [built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: So basically they are the same, right?

Comment: No, they are very different. WAMP uses Apache (**W**indows **A**pache **M**ySQL **P**HP) which is a production grade HTTP server. The built-in PHP server should only be used locally for development work

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation !

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can explicitly define the host and the port with artisan serve command:

`php artisan serve --host=somedomain.com --port=8001`

Note: Remember to enable to port with your firewall.

Comment: Yes I am using the command, but it is showing the same error.
"$ php artisan serve --host=blog.local --port=8001
Laravel development server started: <http://blog.local:8001>
[Tue May 22 12:35:45 2018] Failed to listen on blog.local:8001 (reason: php_netw
ork_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. )
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such
host is known.  in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br /> "

Comment: try these first: `php artisan config:cache`  `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Can you try some other port like `--port=8888`

Comment: what is your laravel version?

Comment: It is 5.6.22. php is 7.2.4

Comment: @ProteetiProva did this ever solve you situation?? If not, why was it marked as the correct answer?

Comment: @SolomonAntoine yes it did, after i enabled to port it with firewall

Comment: @ProteetiProva hi, how did you fix the issue on the error? i can't seem to fix it on my end, I already opened the port on my firewall, what do you mean exactly by enabled to port it with firewall?

Comment: @Roljhon I think I followed this link : https://www.windowscentral.com/how-open-port-windows-firewall

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for just this solution - more the host/domain than the port.

Comment: Worked for me.

Other configs in .env of the Laravel app were:

SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,localhost:8080

Frontend app, Vue, was running on port 8080:

http://localhost:8080

Comment: in my case this is my solution sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf

Answer (score 16):

Though it is too late.

Make an entry in the system host file. in case of windows it is at

**C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts**

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1           blog.local
```

Then run your command:

```
php artisan serve --host=blog.local --port=8001
```

Answer (score 8):

It's easy, just pass the `--host` parameter.

```
php artisan serve --host=example.com
```

Comment: Or even just `0.0.0.0` to bind to all local addresses

Answer (score 6):

Try this command.
`php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 5):

First of all you will need to add your local domain in the `host` file. The path is `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and you will found the `host` file.

Open with notepad and write this line `127.0.0.1 <your_domain_name>` to the last line. For example `127.0.0.1 lala.com`

Then the command on your terminal,

```
php artisan serve --host=<your_domain_name_in_the_host_file>
```

and system will auto generate a port number for you like

```
php artisan serve --host=lala.com
Laravel development server started: http://lala.com:8000
```

Now then, you are able to surf your localhost, which is `http://lala.com:8000` with your custom domain name but also with the port number.

If you want a custom port number then just specify the port number at the end of the command,

```
php artisan serve --host=lala.com --port=8088
```

and url will be `http://lala.com:8088`

Answer (score 3):

Try to command like this:

```
php artisan serve --host=<host IP address> --port=<port to use>
```

Example:

```
php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:
php artisan serve --host 192.168.0.1 --port 80

> Change your host and port